# How to create a graph of 2n nodes on a circle w/ each node is connected to all others except the opposite node + f(n) on either side of the opposite

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx

I would like to create a graph that puts 2n points spaced uniformly on a unit circle, and connects each node to all other nodes except the opposite node, as well as k nodes on either side of the opposite node, where k is a function of n.

I am using the NetworkX package to create the graph.

I know how to manually specify the number of nodes to exclude on either side of the opposite node, but I don't know how to use a function of n instead of doing it manually. I'm sure it is quite simple, but how can this be done?

For example, the code below will exclude the opposite node as well as 5 nodes on either side of the opposite node.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_circle_graph(n):
    G = nx.Graph()
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 2*n, endpoint=False)
    for i in range(2*n):
        G.add_node(i, pos=np.array([np.cos(theta[i]), np.sin(theta[i])]))
        for j in range(i+1, 2*n):
            if (i + n) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n + 1) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n - 1) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n + 2) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n - 2) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n + 3) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n - 3) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n + 4) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n - 4) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n + 5) % (2 * n) != j and (i + n - 5) % (2 * n) != j:
                G.add_edge(i, j)
    return G


n = 10
G = create_circle_graph(n)
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difficulty is to find the appropriate `if` statement while creating the edges. Once you figure that part out the rest is pretty straightforward since you can use `nx.circular_layout(G)` to automatically position your nodes.

Below is a possible approach for this task:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_circle_graph(n,k): #2*n the number and k the radius of the neighborhood
    G = nx.Graph()
    [G.add_node(i) for i in range(2*n)] # create nodes
    for i in range(2*n):
      for j in range(2*n):
        if i<j and (j-i<n-k or j-i>n+k): #appropriate if statement for this task
          G.add_edge(i,j)
    return G
```

And here is an example of the code with n=5 and varying values for k:

```py
n=5
fig,axs=plt.subplots(1,5,figsize=(15,10))

for k,ax in enumerate(fig.axes): #loop through k and subplots
  G=create_circle_graph(n,k)
  posG=nx.circular_layout(G) #set up positions for the nodes
  ax.set_title('k='+str(k))
  nx.draw(G,pos=posG,with_labels=True,ax=ax)
  ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]